# Extends type of accepted props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that's root node can be overridden with the value of passed prop.

```js
interface Props {
  propA?: string
  as?: React.ElementType
}

const OverridableComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const { as: Tag = 'div', ...otherProps } = props

  return <Tag {...props} />
}
```

And another component that will be used as `as`.

```js
interface SomeComponentProps {
  propB: string //<-- mandatory prop
  children?: React.ReactNode
}

const SomeComponent = (props: SomeComponentProps) => {
  return <div someProp={props.propB}>{props.children}</div>
}
```

So, the result that I would love to achieve is something like this

```js
<OverridableComponent propA='optionalProp' as={SomeComponent} />
```

and I'd like `OverridableComponent` to merge props from `SomeComponent`.

```js
<OverridableComponent propA='optionalProp' as={SomeComponent} 
propB={/*required form SomeComponentProps */'someValue />
```

To implement this I tried to use generics.

```js
type Props<T extends ElementType> = {
  propA?: string
  as?: T
} & React.ComponentProps<T>
```

it works for the case when `as` prop is passed, but if it's not, every passed prop even `from='string'` is allowed, because it's allowed on SVG attributes of React.ElementType.

Any idea how to improve this case?

Answer (score 1):

Is it viable for you to pass the required `React.ElementType` explicitely as [Generic type arguments in JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements)? Doing that, you do not rely on compiler inference and can narrow the type properly.

Component:

```
const AppWithComponent = () => (
  <OverridableComponent<typeof SomeComponent>
    propA="pa"
    propB="pb"
    // className="ajsf" ; error 
    // from='string' ; error
    as={SomeComponent}
  />
);
```

Intrinsic Element:

```
const AppWithIntrinsicElementExplicit = () => (
  <OverridableComponent<"div">
    propA="pa"
    // propB="pb" ; error
    className="yehaa"
    // from='string' ; error
    as="div" // you also can drop this attribute
  />
);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57749285-jnvs4)

Comment: Well, I'd like to avoid using type inside jsx, but that's an option, thanks